# How to elegantly combine and format an Ruby array?

Tags: arrays, ruby, formatting

I have an array of countries and lists of states. When I see a state list, I want to combine that with the country just before it with parentheses.

Example array: 
`["United Kingdom",[],"United States", ["Arkansas","Massachusetts","Alaska"],"China",[]]`

I want to format the array into 
`["United Kingdom", "United States (Arkansas, Massachusetts, Alaska)", "China"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def pretty_format arr
   arr.each_slice(2).map do |country, states|
     "#{country}#{states.length > 0 ? ' (' + states.join(', ') +')': ''}"
   end
end
```

```
pretty_format ["United Kingdom", [], "United States",
  ["Arkansas", "Massachusetts","Alaska"],"China",[]]
  #=> ["United Kingdom", "United States (Arkansas, Massachusetts, Alaska)",
  #    "China"]
```

Comment: When replying to a comment you should include the target's username (e.g. "@cary, you're ...") so that they will be notified of the comment by SO. I suggest you replace ", for instance, should yield the example output" with `#=> ["United Kingdom", "United States (Arkansas, Massachusetts, Alaska)", "China"]` properly formatted. You can delete your comment above. When you've done so I'll delete this one.

Comment: bsam, I see you haven't quite got the hang of formatting at SO. When you want to highlight blocks of code indent 4 spaces or align left, select the code and click on `{}` above the edit box. Surround code with backticks (`\``) to highlight it when it is within text. Click on "edited X minutes ago" to see the edit history. (My addition of `#<p></p>` is stylistic only.) I suggest formatting so that readers do not have to scroll horizontally to read it.) Hello @Arup. I've compared the return value with the content of my comment 3 times and fail to understand your point.

Comment: @CarySwoveland the output were far right.. so I read it wrong. :)